# No suitable driver found for jdbc:path - SQL Lite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, netbeans

I have searched through a couple of the questions, which have already been answered but most of them were for mysql.
I have an issue with my program, as it does not connect to the database.

```
Connection conn = null;

public static Connection ConnectDb() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.sqlite:C:\\Users\\Emerald\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ITPAT\\DietTracker.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established");
        return conn;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize. The code is up now.

Comment: Are you sure that `org.sqlite.JDBC` is on your classpath?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. Thank you for your help.